# "Your browsing history" on Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I wrote a Google Chrome extension. All I want to do is provide the ability to open a new tab of a particular url. In order to do so I included the "tab" permission in the "manifest.json" file. Everything works.

Now, when I publish my extension, it says my extension can access "your browsing history". I don't need/want to do anything with the opened tabs. I don't like the fact that is is sort of implying that my extension can do something that I in no way need. Is there any way to allow me to open a new tab at a particular url from my extension without giving me "your browsing history" rights?

Comment: I believe this is because you can open History into a tab, thereby allowing you access to it...

Comment: With the "tabs" permission you could check which pages the user opened in tabs, by doing so periodically you could record the pages that the user visits. So the warning is justified. However, as @serg already noted - you don't need this permission just to open tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.create()` doesn't require tab permission.

Comment: Yeah, all I wanted to do was open the tab (no additional privileges), so this works fine. :)