# How to view Chrome browsing history on ipad?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I'm not sure which StackExchange site does this question belong to, so asking here.

**Update:**

There is no item 'History' in 'Chrome menu' as suggested here:

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=95589

**Update-2**

It could possibly be done through extensions as suggested here:

["Your browsing history" on Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602489/your-browsing-history-on-google-chrome-extension?rq=1)

but Chrome web store seems to be unavailable for ipad.

Comment: Maybe http://superuser.com/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've asked on both sites: at superuser.com they consider it off-topic; at apple.stackexchange.com there's too little activity to expect an answer.

Comment: Well, it's surly not a programming question...

Comment: Yes, but there could be a programming answer: (1) Maybe there is a way to port 'your browsing history' extension to ipad somehow; (2) if the answer is 'no way', only programmer can explain why :)

Comment: Fair enough, hope somebody can help you.